# How can I update my items in redux state?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have state that looks following:

```js
const initialState = {
    employee: '',
    companyNumber: '',
    insuranceCompany: '',
    workHealthcare: '',
    actionGuide: '',
}
```

And I have screen where I want to update/edit these values.

[image]

And the updated values are shown here in this screen.

[image]

this is my action file:

```js
const UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS'

export const employeeEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS,
  payload: { employee: text },
})

export const companyNumberEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS,
  payload: { companyNumber: text },
})

export const insuranceCompanyEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS,
  payload: { insuranceCompany: text },
})

export const workHealthcareEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS,
  payload: { workHealthcare: text },
})

export const actionGuideEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS,
  payload: { actionGuide: text },
})
```

and this is the reducer file.

```js
const UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS'

const initialState = {
    employee: '',
    companyNumber: '',
    insuranceCompany: '',
    workHealthcare: '',
    actionGuide: '',
}

const workplaceValueReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employee: action.payload.employee,
        companyNumber: action.payload.companyNumber,
        insuranceCompany: action.payload.insuranceCompany,
        workHealthcare: action.payload.workHealthcare,
        actionGuide: action.payload.actionGuide
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default workplaceValueReducer
```

This is the screen and the function that should save the edited values.

```js
  const saveWorkPlaceDetails = () => {
    if (employee.length > 0) {
      //   props.editWorkplaceDetails(
      //     employee,
      //     companyNumber,
      //     insuranceCompany,
      //     workHealthcare,
      //     info,
      //   )
      props.saveEmployee(employee)
      props.saveCompanyNumber(companyNumber)
      props.saveInsuranceCompany(insuranceCompany)
      props.saveWorkHealthcare(workHealthcare)
      props.saveActionGuide(info)
      setEmployee('')
      setCompanyNumber('')
      setInsuranceCompany('')
      setWorkHealthcare('')
      setInfo('')
      workDetailsSavedToast()
    } else {
      workDetailsErrorToast()
    }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  //editWorkplaceDetails: bindActionCreators(, dispatch),
  saveEmployee: (text) => dispatch(employeeEditAction(text)),
  saveCompanyNumber: (text) => dispatch(companyNumberEditAction(text)),
  saveInsuranceCompany: (text) => dispatch(insuranceCompanyEditAction(text)),
  saveWorkHealthcare: (text) => dispatch(workHealthcareEditAction(text)),
  saveActionGuide: (text) => dispatch(actionGuideEditAction(text)),
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(EditWorkplaceDetails)
```

The input fields looks as following:

```js
      <Input
        style={inputLicenseEdit}
        inputContainerStyle={{
          borderBottomColor: colors.white,
          width: '100%',
        }}
        placeholder='Työnantaja'
        placeholderTextColor={colors.white}
        leftIcon={
          <Ionicons name='ios-person-outline' size={30} color={colors.white} />
        }
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setEmployee(text)
        }}
      />[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Currently when I try to update the items in the state it doesn't update and triggers the error toast instead.

What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set as many case in your reducer switch that you have actions' consts.
Example for one action :

```js
export const UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS'

export const employeeEditAction = (employee) => ({
  type: UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS,
  employee,
})
```

```js
import {UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS, /** ... other actions */} from 'action path';

const workplaceValueReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employee: action.employee
      }
    // ... other cases
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

It looks like you update all your workplace's values at the same time, so you should simply do :

```js
export const UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS'

export const updateWorkPlaceDetailsAction = (details) => ({
  type: UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS,
  details,
})
```

```js
import {UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS} from 'action path';

const workplaceValueReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS:
      return action.details || state;
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I personnaly set both cases, so one action for the whole object, plus  one action foreach object's attributes I want to update

PS : write "js" after your first line backticks block to get code colors

Comment: I had actions under same thing but it didn't update them correctly,  it only added the first value to all of the state items.

Comment: How does effect to the saveDetails function

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Make console.log step by step, in your action functions and in your reducer and you will probalby understand what happend and what is in your variable so what you do wrong.

Comment: It's allright, everything is working :)

Comment: What if I want to have the cars listed under certain user like this. `user: {cars: [{}]}`

Answer (score 0):

> "What if I want to have the cars listed under certain user like this. user: {cars: [{}]}"

(Replied in previous answered)

It depends of what you want to do.
Examples :

```js
// state is your user
const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CAR:
      const nextState = {
        ...state,
        cars: state.cars.slice() // copy array, because all children that ara objects and arrays, should be immutable too
      };
      return nextState;
      newtState.cars.push(action.car); 
      /** can be done like that too, but it consume more performance */
      return {
        ...state,
        cars: [...state.cars, action.car]
      }

    case UPDATE_CAR:
      const nextState = {
        ...state,
        cars: state.cars.slice();
      };
      nextState.cars[action.index] = action.car; 
      /** OR even : */
      nextState.cars[action.index] = {...state.cars[action.index], [action.key]: action.value}
      return nextState;

    case REMOVE_CAR:
      const nextState = {
        ...state,
        cars: state.cars.slice()
      };
      // do not use splice before copying the array and do not return directly splice
      newtState.cars.splice(action.index, 1); 
      return nextState;

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

see documentation for [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: I want to show the cars currently logged in user and when other user logs in they don't see the other user cars

Comment: Hey I made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71510369/how-can-i-add-edit-remove-items-as-specific-user-from-their-details where u probably see better how my setup currently is.