# How can I add, edit, remove items as specific user from their details?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have currently redux set up in a way where people can add their cars and other things and update them but I would need them to show only to that user that is currently logged in.

I created following user reducer that has all the information but not sure if structure is correct and what to change here to make it work as intended.

What I am intending to do here is that it would look something like this so I can filter the data according to who is logged in.

```js
user: [
{    username: '',
    insurances: [],
    cars: [],
    workplace: {
      employer: '',
      companyNumber: '',
      insuranceCompany: '',
      workHealthcare: '',
      actionGuide: '',
    } },
]
```

userReducer:

```js
const ADD_USER = 'ADD_USER'
const USER_LOGGED_IN = 'USER_LOGGED_IN'
const ADD_NEW_INSURANCE = 'ADD_NEW_INSURANCE'
const DELETE_EXISTING_INSURANCE = 'DELETE_EXISTING_INSURANCE'
const ADD_NEW_CAR = 'ADD_NEW_CAR'
const DELETE_EXISTING_CAR = 'DELETE_EXISTING_CAR'
const UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS'

const initialState = {
  users: [
    {
      username: '',
      signedIn: false,
      insurances: [],
      cars: [],
      workplace: {
        employer: '',
        companyNumber: '',
        insuranceCompany: '',
        workHealthcare: '',
        actionGuide: '',
      },
    },
  ],
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, { id: state.users.length, ...action.payload }],
      }
    case USER_LOGGED_IN:
      return {
        ...state,
        signedIn: action.payload,
      }
    case ADD_NEW_INSURANCE:
      return {
        ...state,
        insurances: [
          ...state.insurances,
          { id: state.insurances.length, ...action.payload },
        ],
      }
    case DELETE_EXISTING_INSURANCE:
      return {
        insurances: [
          ...state.insurances.filter(
            (insurance) => insurance !== action.payload
          ),
        ],
      }
    case ADD_NEW_CAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        cars: [...state.cars, { id: state.cars.length, ...action.payload }],
      }
    case DELETE_EXISTING_CAR:
      return {
        cars: [...state.cars.filter((car) => car !== action.payload)],
      }
    case UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employer: action.payload.employer,
      }
    case UPDATE_WORKPLACE_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        employee: action.payload.employee,
      }
    case UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        companyNumber: action.payload.companyNumber,
      }
    case UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        insuranceCompany: action.payload.insuranceCompany,
      }
    case UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        workHealthcare: action.payload.workHealthcare,
      }
    case UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        actionGuide: action.payload.actionGuide,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default userReducer
```

Here is my action files currently:

```js
const ADD_NEW_CAR = 'ADD_NEW_CAR'
const DELETE_EXISTING_CAR = 'DELETE_EXISTING_CAR'

export const addNewCar = (text) => ({
    type: ADD_NEW_CAR,
    payload: text
})

export const deleteExistingCar = (car) => ({
    type: DELETE_EXISTING_CAR,
    payload: car
})

const ADD_NEW_INSURANCE = 'ADD_NEW_INSURANCE'
const DELETE_EXISTING_INSURANCE = 'DELETE_EXISTING_INSURANCE'

export const addInsurance = (text) => ({
    type: ADD_NEW_INSURANCE,
    payload: text
})

export const deleteExistingInsurance = (insurance) => ({
    type: DELETE_EXISTING_INSURANCE,
    payload: insurance
})

const UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS'
const UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS = 'UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS'

export const employeeEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS,
  payload: { employee: text },
})

export const companyNumberEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_COMPANYNUMBER_DETAILS,
  payload: { companyNumber: text },
})

export const insuranceCompanyEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_INSURANCECOMPANY_DETAILS,
  payload: { insuranceCompany: text },
})

export const workHealthcareEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_WORKHEALTHCARE_DETAILS,
  payload: { workHealthcare: text },
})

export const actionGuideEditAction = (text) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ACTIONGUIDE_DETAILS,
  payload: { actionGuide: text },
})

const USER_LOGGED_IN = 'USER_LOGGED_IN'

export const authAction = (trueFalse) => ({
    type: USER_LOGGED_IN,
    payload: trueFalse,
  });
```

and this is my auth reducer:

```js
const USER_LOGGED_IN = 'USER_LOGGED_IN'

const initialState = {
  signedIn: false,
}

const authsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGGED_IN:
      return {
        ...state,
        signedIn: action.payload,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
export default authsReducer
```

Comment: In your auth initial state add loggedInUserId. Add it to the payload when dispatching an action. Filter inside reducer.

Comment: And filter inside reducer?

Comment: You have an array of users in state. Each "item" of array has signedIn which is a boolean, and cars array. If only one user can be logged in at one point in time, then you can select user with signedIn property set to true and do update wanted data. There is also a library that supports multi user applications. https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/advanced/multi-user-applications/

Comment: User is authenticated using gognito and amplify authentication with aws. I can get current authenticated user but data isn't stored to any actual database